# ASP.NET MVC best way to manipulate application settings?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my appication I need to have some settings, which must be editable by administrator. For example: some string or numerable values, text for link's href attribute and flag for this link, which determines to show this link in layout or not, etc. This settings must be accessible in views, controllers after application starts.

I can save this settings in XML-file, I thought, and get to administrator UI to edit this settings... But, in which way I can access this settings in runtime? Or there is better way to do this?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer json and https://github.com/Dynalon/JsonConfig for settings. Example from github:

```
// there is no need to have LoadedModules OR HttpServer in your
// default.conf, if missing this will just evaluate to false
if (Config.Global.LoadedModules.HttpServer) {
    // start HttpServer
}
```

Comment: Thank! I installed JsonConfig package. Can you give me simple example of usage in View? And where I must create default.conf json-file?

Comment: Add **default.conf** in project, change **Build Action** to **Embedded Resource** and now you can use `Config.Default.SomethingInJson`

Comment: Thank! I did it. Everything is OK.